# C memory leak when freeing char pointer in linked list

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory-leaks, linked-list

I have a code creates a linked list of values that can be of different types, e.g. strings or doubles. However, at the end of the program, after freeing the linked list, I am left with a memory leak due to the way I have added strings into it. The code I have is something like the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// compile with: gcc test_list.c -o test_list
// to check memory leaks run:
// >> valgrind --leak-check=full -v ./test_list

typedef enum tagParamType {
  TYPE_double_t = 0,
  TYPE_string_t
} ParamType;

size_t TypeSize[2] = {
  sizeof(double),
  sizeof(const char*)
};

typedef struct tagParam {
  char name[1024];       /* Parameter name */
  void *value;           /* Parameter value */
  ParamType type;        /* type of parameter */
  struct tagParam *next;
} Param;

typedef struct tagParameters {
  Param *head;
} Parameters;

void AddParam( Parameters *pars, const char *name, const void *value, ParamType type );
void RemoveParameters( Parameters *pars );
Parameters *CreateParameters( );
void PrintParameters( Parameters *pars );

void AddParam( Parameters *pars, const char *name, const void *value, ParamType type ){
  Param *par = NULL;
  par = malloc(sizeof(Param));
  memset(par, 0, sizeof(Param)); // set everything to 0

  par->value = (void *)malloc( TypeSize[type] );
  memcpy( par->value, value, TypeSize[type] );
  strncpy( par->name, name, 1024 );
  par->type = type;

  par->next = pars->head;
  pars->head = par;
}

void RemoveParameters( Parameters *pars ){
  Param *this, *next = NULL;
  this = pars->head;

  if ( this ) { next = this->next; }

  while ( this ){
    free( this->value );
    free( this );
    this = next;
    if ( this ) { next = this->next; }
  }

  pars->head = NULL;
}

Parameters *CreateParameters( ){
  Parameters *pars = calloc(sizeof(*pars), 1);

  /* add a string */
  const char *svalue = strdup("Matthew");
  AddParam( pars, "First name", &svalue, TYPE_string_t );

  /* add a double */
  double dvalue = 0.1;
  AddParam( pars, "A number", &dvalue, TYPE_double_t );

  return pars;
}

void PrintParameters( Parameters *pars ){
  Param *this, *next = NULL;
  this = pars->head;
  if ( this ) { next = this->next; }
  while ( this ){
    if ( this->type == TYPE_double_t ) { fprintf( stdout, "%s is %lf\n", this->name, *(double*)this->value ); }
    else if ( this->type == TYPE_string_t ) { fprintf( stdout, "%s is %s\n", this->name, *(char**)this->value ); }
    this = next;
    if ( this ) { next = this->next; }
  }
}

int main (){
  Parameters *pars = CreateParameters( );
  PrintParameters( pars );
  RemoveParameters( pars );

  return 0;
}
```

Could I add string parameters to the linked list in a different way, or free them in a different way, that would avoid the memory leak? Freeing the `svalue` string in the `CreateParameters()` function leads to it being removed from the linked list, despite the `memcpy` of the variable.

Sorry if this is a duplicate, and the answer is available elsewhere.

**Edited version** of code that fixed leaks:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// compile with: gcc -g test_list.c -o test_list
// to check memory leaks run:
// >> valgrind --leak-check=full -v ./test_list

typedef enum tagParamType {
  TYPE_double_t = 0,
  TYPE_string_t
} ParamType;

size_t TypeSize[2] = {
  sizeof(double),
  sizeof(const char*)
};

typedef struct tagParam {
  char name[1024];       /* Parameter name */
  void *value;           /* Parameter value */
  ParamType type;        /* type of parameter */
  struct tagParam *next;
} Param;

typedef struct tagParameters {
  Param *head;
} Parameters;

void AddParam( Parameters *pars, const char *name, const void *value, ParamType type );
void RemoveParameters( Parameters *pars );
Parameters *CreateParameters( );
void PrintParameters( Parameters *pars );

void AddParam( Parameters *pars, const char *name, const void *value, ParamType type ){
  Param *par = NULL;
  par = malloc(sizeof(Param));
  memset(par, 0, sizeof(Param)); // set everything to 0

  if ( type == TYPE_string_t ){
    par->value = (void *)strndup((const char*)value, TypeSize[type]);
  }
  else{
    par->value = (void *)malloc( TypeSize[type] );
    memcpy( par->value, value, TypeSize[type] );
  }
  strncpy( par->name, name, 1024 );
  par->type = type;

  par->next = pars->head;
  pars->head = par;
}

void RemoveParameters( Parameters *pars ){
  Param *this, *next = NULL;
  for ( this = pars->head, next = this->next ; this; ){
    free( this->value );
    free( this );
    this = next;
    if ( this ){ next = this->next; }
  }

  pars->head = NULL;
}

Parameters *CreateParameters( ){
  Parameters *pars = calloc(sizeof(*pars), 1);

  /* add a string */
  const char *svalue = strdup("Matthew");
  AddParam( pars, "First name", (const void*)svalue, TYPE_string_t );

  /* add a double */
  double dvalue = 0.1;
  AddParam( pars, "A number", &dvalue, TYPE_double_t );

  free((char*)svalue);
  return pars;
}

void PrintParameters( Parameters *pars ){
  Param *this, *next = NULL;
  for ( this = pars->head, next = this->next ; this; ){
    if ( this->type == TYPE_double_t ) { fprintf( stdout, "%s is %lf\n", this->name, *(double*)this->value ); }
    else if ( this->type == TYPE_string_t ) { fprintf( stdout, "%s is %s\n", this->name, (char*)this->value ); }
    this = next;
    if ( this ){ next = this->next; }
  }
}

int main (){
  Parameters *pars = CreateParameters( );
  PrintParameters( pars );
  RemoveParameters( pars );
  free( pars );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of passing pointer to pointer - pass string itself and do the strdup inside the AddParameter (when type is string). Thus avoiding double pointer at printing and problem with freeing - object that allocates memory is responsible for freeing

Comment: `if ( this ) { next = this->next; }
  while ( this ){ ... ` a for loop would be simpler here.

Comment: Thanks @ArtemyVysotsky - I've made some edits (see above) and it now doesn't leak.

Comment: @joop - yes, a for loop would be simpler. I've posted a corrected version of the code which also includes for loops when printing and freeing the linked list values.

Comment: Still overly complicated how about `for ( this = pars->head; this; this=next) {  next = this->next; free( this->value );
    free( this ); }` ?